# Is KubeFlow still supported on GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to use KubeFlow on GCP and I am following this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kubeflow-introduction/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2), but "[click-to-deploy](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-ui/)" is no longer supported so I followed the documentation of "[kubectl and kpt](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/)". However, I keep getting this "`You cannot perform this action because the Cloud SDK component manager is disabled for this installation.`" error and none of the solutions I found worked. I have 2 other friends told me they tried to make KubeFlow work since last year, it never worked, but I did see people post question about KubeFlow on Stackoverflow still, so I want to ask **if it is still working, if so, where can I find a decent guide to follow**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, as the [kubectl and kpt](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/) says, the first step in getting prepared to install cluster is installing [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) that is CLI that manages authentication, local configuration, developer workflow, interactions with [Google Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis).
Without is you simply cant work with objects(in your case you need to enable `kpt anthoscli beta`) and perform tasks like

> creating a Compute Engine VM instance, managing a Google Kubernetes
> Engine cluster, and deploying an App Engine application, either from
> the command line or in scripts and other automations..

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working. For that error message, it turned out that I just didn't install the Cloud SDK properly. There will be a lot of other issues too down the road, but at least the KubeFlow web UI is working for me now.